# Android different ABI compatibility

Tags: android, android-ndk

For example let build static library called "some".

**LibSome Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := some
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := some.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

**LibSome Application.mk**

```
APP_MODULES := somelib
APP_OPTIM  := release
```

And get armeabi version of our lib in *LibSome/obj/local/armeabi/libsome.a*

So now we need to drop our lib to mainProject jni folder and use it

**MainProject Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := some
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsome.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/some
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mainProject
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mainProject.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := some
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But there are different ABI like mips, x86, armeabi-v7a and we can get all supported versions of somelib by current ndk just adding

```
APP_ABI:= all
```

to SomeLib Application.mk, so we get *LibSome/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libsome.a*, *LibSome/obj/local/x86/libsome.a* etc

**Main question** - do i really need to think about different ABI and create project for every supported ABI like mainProjectx86, mainProjectMIPS with different ABI builded libs?

And secondary questions are:

If i build project for armeabi ABI (default) how many devices will be cut out? Can armeabi-v7a ABI device run armeabi ABI app?

If there is a way to have one project with different set of pre-builded libs? So if you build mainProject for ameabi-v7a it will use armeabi-v7a libs and so on?

Comment: As far as I know, armeabi-v7a is backward compatible with v6 and v5 (which is armeabi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, So firstly, if your are using standard C calls without any architecture specific assembly language embedded, it's safe to use `APP_ABI := all`. This will allow **gcc** to create libs for all architectures and your app will have no problems running.

if however, you are using something specific to ARM, e.g. NEON architecture calls for optimized math or Intel x86 SSE3 calls for optimized math, then APP_ABI := all may not be a good idea. This might lead to runtime errors which are very difficult to understand. Then you may be required to maintain different projects for different architectures.

Coming to secondary question:
1. Most of the latest devices are armeabi-v7a, so only the older devices will be cut out. Also parallel x86 and MIPS devices will also be cut out. But since most flagships like Samsung, HTC and Sony ship with ARM, your app will be reachable to a big percentage.

Not much clue on the second one for now.

Answer (score 1):

All ARM devices run armeabi. The older and slower ones use ARMv6, and cannot use armeabi-v7a libraries. But it is possible to mix armeabi and ameabi-v7a shared libraries in one application. This may come useful if you have a huge native library which you don't want to ship in two copies, and also some very specific function that is a performance bottleneck which may be vastly accelerated with NEON optimizations. So, in the end you have the following structure in your project folder:

```
libs/
    armeabi/
            libhuge.so
            libslow.so
    armeabi-v7a/
            libfast.so
```